# Deterministic asymmetric encryption in .NET?

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I have a multi agent application that communicates with central server, each agent have unique identifier (Guid) which has to be held in secret, however the server needs to be able to correctly differ agents from one another. I can't hold agent identifiers as is on server, because server can be hacked, identifiers can be dumped and personal user data can be leaked that way. I can't hold identifier hash (like MD5 or SHA*), because at some point I need to decrypt identifiers (I take all data from central server and perform some analysis, which require agent identifier to be known).

I thought about using RSA (store public keys on agents and encrypted identifiers on server), but each time I encrypt agent identifier I get unique value (because RSA adds random padding to data), so RSA is not deterministic. How can I transform agent identifiers in deterministic and cryptographically secure way?

Comment: So, you don´t want to store the data on the server because it could be compromitted, but the RSA private key is ok on the server? ... Btw., RSA itself is deterministic; the padding is a independent step. You could do the padding yourself in a non-random way, but there are some security problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Attacks_against_plain_RSA

Comment: @deviantfan I wasn't going to store private key on central server, I was going to store encrypted identifiers on server. I'd store the private key only on the agent that takes all data from central server and perform analysis. And I know that if I do padding myself, the private key can be compomised more easily. I'm looking for some adequate solution for this...

Comment: Where you write "asynchronous" you mean "asymmetric", right?

Comment: @CodesInChaos oh, yes... obviously it is. Thank you, I've fixed the title.

Answer (score 0):

How about: The analysis server holds a pairing of (true ID , pseudo ID) for each agent. The pseudo ID is encrypted by the agent public key and held in the agent. The agent decrypts this with its private key when sending it to the central server.

Only the analysis server knows the true ID of the agent. The pseudo ID is known to all three, and is kept encrypted on the agent. The pseudo ID can be from a random distribution, appearing to be encrypted data.